# Importing a workspace with qualifier

Tags: import, apl, dyalog

In a namespace script I would like to use a couple of functions from the *dfns* workspace. However, if I do `⎕CY 'dfns'` all identifiers in *dfns* will be imported unqualified. How do I import *dfns* so that I can access functions in *dfns* with a qualifier, e.g. `dfns.vtrim`? Do I first need to create a namespace named *dfns*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import all of the dfns workspace into a namespace called `dfns` with:

```apl
:Namespace Test
  'dfns'⎕NS ⍬
  dfns.⎕CY'dfns'
:EndNamespace
```

```apl
      Test.dfns.pco ⍳10
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///38ovMTe1uCAxOVUhJLW4hEtBQT0lLa9Y/VHfVL9ghUe9a4AiIAE9oIBzJESOy8o1LwWu7/9/kEY9sKKC5Hygns2GBgA)

Comment: As far as I understand, your example imports three functions into the namespace (script) Test. However, what I would like to do is to import the "identifier" *dfns* only and access the functions with *dfns* as a prefix/qualifier, e.g. `dfns.vtrim` or `dfns.pco`. The advantage of this approach is that I don't pollute the namespace and I can immediately tell where the functions in *dfns* come from.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Sorry about that. It should be correct now.